# Replacing letters in Python given a specific condition

Tags: python

Original code:

```
meds = [ "tuberculin Cap(s)", "tylenol Cap(s)", "tramadol 2 Cap(s)"]


for i in meds:
    new_meds = i.replace(" Cap(s)", " 1 Cap(s)")

    print(new_meds)
```

The output is:

```
 tuberculin 1 Cap(s)
 tylenol 1 Cap(s)
 tramadol 2 1 Cap(s)
```

I'm trying to replace all the meds with just "Caps(s)" into "1 Cap(s)"
the first 2 meds were right however the 3rd one results in "tramadol 2 1 Cap(s)".

How should I correct my script, so that all meds with a number within the string don't get modified?

The end result should be that only the meds like "tuberculin Cap(s)", "tylenol Cap(s)" get modified and not "tramadol 2 Cap(s)".

Comment: So you only want to replace `' Cap(s)'` with `' 1 Cap(s)'` (why not get rid of the `'(s)'`?) when there isn't a number before it already? Your code doesn't even attempt to do that. You should probably look into regular expressions (using the `re` module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can use a regular expression with the [re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall):**

```
import re
meds = [ "tuberculin Cap(s)", "tylenol Cap(s)", "tramadol 2 Cap(s)"]
meds = [med.replace(" Cap(s)", " 1 Cap(s)") if len(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+ \d+ Cap\(s\)", med)) == 0 else med for med in meds]
print meds
```

**The above prints**

```
['tuberculin 1 Cap(s)', 'tylenol 1 Cap(s)', 'tramadol 2 Cap(s)']
```

**Breaking it down, as asked**:

It seems you are unfamiliar with [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). In python, any iterable can be looped over, like you did with your for loop. In addition, you can use a list comprehension:

```
lst = ["one", "two", "three"]
print [element for element in lst]
```

This prints `['one', 'two', 'three']`.

**Now to the [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).**

- Square brackets (sets) in a regex means "choose any of the characters inside". Therefore, the set `[ab]` would match both `a` and `b`.
- In sets, you can have ranges. `[a-e]` matches any character from `a` to `e` (inclusive).
- A `+` in regex means "one or more of the thing to the left" - `[ab]+` would therefore match any combination of 1 or more a's and/or b's.
- `\d` matches any digit (can be replaced by [0-9]).
- Any character that has a special meaning in regex - like '**(**' or '**)**' which indicate a group - must be [escaped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) or put inside square brackets to be matched.

My regex has three main parts; `[a-z]+`, `\d+` and `Cap\(s\)`. Combining them matches:

"Any combination of 1 or more letters followed by a space" **+** "one or more digits followed by a space" **+** "The text 'Cap(s)'".

`re.findall(pattern, string)` returns a list containing all the matches against `pattern` found in `string`. Its length being `0` therefore means there were no matches. In your case, that means there were no "medication name **+** number **+** 'Cap(s)'".

While you could achieve the same for this input simply by checking whether the string contains any digits, this makes sure it follows the explicit pattern of "word + number + 'Cap(s)'".

**Allow digits in medication name**

If you wanted to allow any sequence as the medication name (e.g. molecular formula with numbers), you could change the regex to `[a-zA-Z\d]+ \d+ Cap\(s\)`, allowing any lower- or uppercase letter as well as digits to be part of the name.

**Using a for loop**

If you wanted to write the code more clearly without the use of a list comprehension, you could do it with a regular `for` loop:

```
for index, med in enumerate(meds):
  if len(re.findall("[a-zA-Z\d]+ \d+ Cap\(s\)", med)) == 0:
    meds[index] = med.replace(" Cap(s)", " 1 Cap(s)")
```

Note that to change a value in a list within a `for` loop, you need the index of the element you want to change (hence the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)). If you find the `enumerate` confusing, it can be written like this:

```
for i in xrange(len(meds)):
  if len(re.findall("[a-zA-Z\d]+ \d+ Cap\(s\)", meds[i])) == 0:
    meds[i] = meds[i].replace(" Cap(s)", " 1 Cap(s)")
```

**Enumerate**

To expand on use of the `enumerate` function in the for loop: `enumerate` returns a list of [tuples](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) containing the index in the list (or any sequence) along with the element: `(index, element)`. In python, you can unpack the values in a tuple: `a,b = (1,2)`. `a` is now `1` and `b` is `2`.

Comment: can you break the code down for me? Is med a variable like "i" in a for loop? if len(re.findall(".+[0-9]+ Cap\(s\)", med)) == 0 what does this mean?

im new to python so pardon newbness

Comment: I kinda understand your solution better . i tested it on my own idle but im very new to this. let's say for example. we did it the old fashioned way. without using the list comprehenesion and using only the for loop. how would that look like?. thank you very much for that thorough breakdown. Im  learning a lot

Comment: thank you so much! now I understand it so much better now!!

btw. how did you learn python? did you go to school for it? if so what course did you take? because I wan't to learn a lot more of it

Comment: Me learning python was solely a product of procrastination whilst studying for an exam in a boring subject. I started out using it to solve problems on https://projecteuler.net/.

Comment: so that's it? no formal education? so it's all autodidact? dang 

where would you recommend I start? I looked up project euler and only got past the 1st question :/ because I didn't understand the other questions

Comment: I can add that I do hand in a master thesis in complex computer systems in 3 weeks, answering questions on SO is my current procrastination :-P while I haven't explicitly learned python from any subject, I have learned programming *concepts* that are applicable across languages. Perhaps you should take a look at the "beginner" section and then the "game" section on https://pythonspot.com/

Comment: thanks I'll check out that website. thank you again very much for the time :D

Answer (score 0):

Using List Comprehension

```
In [35]: meds
Out[35]: ['tuberculin Cap(s)', 'tylenol Cap(s)', 'tramadol 2 Cap(s)']

In [36]: new_meds=[ i.replace(" Cap(s)", " 1 Cap(s)") if any(char.isdigit() for char in i) == False  else i for i in meds]

In [37]: new_meds
Out[37]: ['tuberculin 1 Cap(s)', 'tylenol 1 Cap(s)', 'tramadol 2 Cap(s)']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegEx this way:

```
import re
meds = [ "tuberculin Cap(s)", "tylenol Cap(s)", "tramadol 2 Cap(s)"]

for i in meds:
    if not re.match(".+\d.+", i):
        new_meds = i.replace(" Cap(s)", " 1 Cap(s)")
    else:
        new_meds = i
    print(new_meds)
```

Output:

```
tuberculin 1 Cap(s)
tylenol 1 Cap(s)
tramadol 2 Cap(s)
```

Expression `".+\d.+"` will find item that has "something + digit + something".